# The ViewPager is executing a wrong fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a problem with my ViewPager. I'm using custom ImageButtons to swipe between fragments. The problem is, when I try to swipe from third fragment to fourth (case 3) fragment, the fifth(case 4) fragment is executed(without fragment UI) and then is showed fourth fragment. Thanks

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: return ScreenSlidePageJobTitle.newInstance();
                case 1: return ScreenSlidePageJobDescription.newInstance();
                case 2: return ScreenSlidePageJobLocation.newInstance();
                case 3: return ScreenSlidePageJobPrice.newInstance();
                case 4: return ScreenSlidePageJobToDb.newInstance();
                default: return ScreenSlidePageJobToDb.newInstance();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }

    public void setSlide(int slide, boolean scroll) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(slide, scroll);
    }

    public int getItem() {
        return mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
    }
}
```

I'm using this functionality to swipe

```
nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(checkLocation())
                {
                    int slide = ((AddItemFragment)(getParentFragment())).getItem() + 1;
                    ((AddItemFragment)(getParentFragment())).setSlide(slide, true);
                }
            }
        });
```

// edit
mViewPager is declared as global variable and define in onCreateView

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_item, container, false);

        mViewPager = rootView.findViewById(R.id.add_item_view_pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences(JOB_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the mViewPager variable defined?

Comment: in viewpager it maintain the state of both consecutive fragments

Comment: How do you know "the fifth(case 4) fragment is executed(without fragment UI)"

Comment: Added code with mViewPager. I added Toast to fifth fragment which shows when I swipe to fourth

Comment: it will automatically gets loaded its behaviour of view pager if you want to something perform then u can go with setUserVisibleHint or use once setOffscreenPageLimit method and pass to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default ViewPager retains 1 fragment on either side of the current fragment. Check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code:

```
viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
```

This code solve your problem.